# Properly read unicode characters in console / InputStream

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I have 2 Windows applications where I want to test reading and writing Unicode characters. I know about other IPC possibilities, but I would like to understand why this particulat case is not working.

Here is the readinput.cpp:

```
int wmain()
{
    std::wstring temp;
    std::getline(std::wcin, temp);

    // this line is only for debugging purpose, to view string representation in memory
    uint8_t * p = (uint8_t*)temp.data();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is writeoutput.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var process = new Process();

    process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\...\\readinput.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    process.Start()      
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Hello from \u03A6\u0429\u3427");

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

I think that the C# application is correctly writing to my reader's input stream. However, the C++ application will not display a correct input, see image. This is the same, regardless if I use std::cin or std::wcin.

[image]

Comment: What's the point of `WriteLine("Hello from \u03A6\u0429\u3427"`? Stings in .NET are UTF16. The encoding can't be changed by using escape sequences. You could just type the characters you want instead of using escape sequences. Unicode/UTF8 aren't escape sequences, they're a specific way to convert (encode) characters to bytes and vice-versa

Comment: if you use \u code, you are 100% sure that you'll have this character. Otherwise, it is dependent on the editor and the encoding of the source file.

Comment: Wrong and this page proves this. Stack Overflow is an ASP.NET Core application and this is a UTF8 page. `and the encoding of the source file.` fix your settings. That's the same problem as this question - the application is using the wrong encoding because it assumes that a simple cast will somehow convert between codepages

Comment: To put it another way, people outside the US and Western Europe don't type escape sequences into their documents.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the problem. It has nothing to do with page encoding, I am sending a correct string from C#, but C++ is receiveng different garbage.

Comment: I understand the problem perfectly - Greek has no English characters and I've actually had to run `chcp` back in the DOS days to switch a terminal's codepage. Something you still have to do in consoles or Linux shells etc. I also got one of the first editions of "Effective C++" that warned against using C coee instead of C++ streams. I also remember that .NET Framework will use the system's non-Unicode encoding aka system locale, while .NET Core (including .NET 5+) will use UTF8.

Comment: And I know .NET has no problem with Unicode, one way or another, which is why I can type Αυτό Εδώ and Φυστικοβούτυρο and expect to appear properly

Comment: Then why is the string not correctly received by C++ app?

Comment: @AndreiM If you launch cmd.exe and run `chcp`, does it indicate the active code page is 437? The symptoms you see could be explained if we suppose that the .Net process is converting the Unicode string using the console default code page. For en-US system locale, the default OEM / console code page is 437, and U+03A6 would get converted to 0xE8. The default Windows "ANSI" codepage is 1252, and and in cp 1252 0xE8 is U+00E8 "è".

Comment: 437 is indeed the console codepage.

Comment: @PeterConstable I also tried in my C++ program to `setlocale(".utf8")` and try to read the input string as an utf8 string of chars, but the input memory buffer is identical in my C app, regardless of any change I've made so far in the C app.

Comment: Before `process.Start()`, try setting `process.StartInfo.StandardInputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode`.

Comment: @AndreiM Or after `process.Start()`, try checking the value of `process.StandardInput.Encoding`.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, when using `Process.Start()`, if an encoding wasn't set in `ProcessStartInfo.StandardInputEncoding`, then .Net will call GetConsoleCP() to get a default encoding, and that will use the OEM code page for the machine's system locale setting. For system locale of en-US, the default console (OEM) code page will be code page 437. When you call `process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Hello from \u03A6\u0429\u3427")`, U+03A6 will get mapped into code page 437 as 0xE8; U+0429 and U+3427 are not supported in code page 437, and so they will get mapped to "?". In the receiving process, `std::getline(std::wcin, temp)` will read 0xE8 as U+00E8 "è".

If you set `process.StartInfo.StandardInputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode` before calling `process.Start()`, then .Net will use UTF-16 when outputting to StandardInput, and all three of those characters should work as expected.

Comment: For some reason, StartInfo does not have a StandardInputEncoding property. I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2, but the documentation says it is only with .NET Core or .NET standard, but not .NET Framework.

Comment: BTW, the process encoding is IBM437, codepage 437, windows codepage 1258, so you're right about the default encoding. But I still don't know how to change that encoding.

Comment: @RemyLebeau first problem is that you have to set the encoding before the process starts, and normally this is done through Process.StartInfo. Second issue is that StandardInput.Encoding is a get only property.